# How to make my Dell Windows 7 Laptop as a Wi-Fi Hotspot to use internet in my iPad?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, wifi-driver

How do I make my Dell Windows 7 Laptop a Wi-Fi Hotspot to use the internet on my iPad?

My modem is not Wi-Fi enabled and I don't have a hardware wireless router.

Answer (score 3):

Use Connectify

http://www.connectify.me/

It also supports wpa/wpa2 psk

You can run that on your windows 7 laptop and enable the soft ap features of windows 7

Alternately you can look at the below tutorial to enable windows 7's hotspot features

http://lifehacker.com/5369381/turn-your-windows-7-pc-into-a-wireless-hotspot

Comment: Thanks but which method will be best

Comment: Connectify works well for me

Comment: @freethinker - Now wi-fi showing connected in iPhone but any website not opening in iphone safari

Comment: well its difficult to say whats wrong, I think connectify has a logging option

Comment: here's a video that might help http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPgrAOuiWuk&hd=1

Comment: It's not working for my iPhone

Comment: don't use connectifi if using i3 or other 64bit processor, ur system will crash.